# FirebaseFirestoreSwift - No Such Module w/ SPM

Tags: firebase, swift-package-manager, xcode13

Xcode 13.1 on a Mac M1. Moving from Cocoapods to SPM. Add the `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git` dependency. One of my classes uses the `@DocumentID` tag which uses `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`. However, even though it is imported in the class I get the error `No such module FirebaseFirestoreSwift`.

It clearly sees this module as when I start typing the import statement, it comes up. However, it won't compile with the error listed above. I tried to remove and reinstall the dependency, but same result. **Numerous** clean build folders and exiting and coming back into Xcode. No joy.

What can I do here?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @rpsutton - Nope...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the FirebaseFirestoreSwift-beta package. See how [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9246)